# grid problem, pls help

Tags: overleaf

I am trying to make a grid but I get an alignment error when I try to align the text on top. Here's my current code.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[xstep=0.5cm,ystep=0.7cm,color=gray] (-1,-.701) grid (1,1.4);
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text width=.5cm,align=top,minimum height=.7cm}]{
A & $\frac{1}{1}$ & C & D \\
B & $\frac{3}{4}$ & $\frac{1}{1}$ & $\frac{3}{5}$ \\
 & a & b & a+b \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The `align` option in the node is for the text, so `top` does not make sense. Is could be, for example, `left,center,right`.

Comment: but the fractions are too low and i want to raise them to the center. its already aligned to the center so i had to raise the alignment so i immediately thoguht of `top` because i didnt think `up` would work